# Is it ok to miss a part of flight?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, missed-flights

If i book a flight that goes for example

London -> Paris -> New York

Is that ok if I miss the London -> Paris flight but get in from Paris? and on return I skip the Paris -> London flight.

I thought it should not be a problem but I remember reading somewhere that airlines do not allow that. Is that true?

Comment: This has been asked -- and answered -- many times on this site. Please see, for example, this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60038/can-i-skip-the-first-of-a-set-of-connecting-flights/60039#60039

Answer (score 1):

With most airlines and for most tickets, your remaining reservations will be cancelled automatically as soon as you miss a flight and your ticket will be valueless. Consult the conditions of carriage of your airline to be sure.

You will not be able to get on the plane at Paris.

If you want to start your journey in Paris then you should buy a ticket originating in Paris.